# Check Sql Spell Programmatically

Tags: c#, sql

I have a .NET program which Get Query And Check Spll it.
this Query maybe very large and run it require so much time.
So I need run Check Splling without run it.
thanks.

### EDIT

Because
My Query maybe **very large** and run it **require so much time**.
my program have two mode:

1- test mode : for test input query 
2- this query will run later and when i want execute this.

Comment: So what's your question exactly?

Comment: you want spell check on SQL? why

Comment: Read up on [ask]. You run the risk of having this "question" closed.

Comment: Try creating a command on your query, and call `Prepare()` on it. This should pass your SQL to RDBMS to build a query plan and cache, but I am not sure if it throws when the query is invalid.

Comment: Prepare() command is for check connection between client and server not for check Spel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than spell checker i guess you mean Syntax checking, in this case you should take a look at the [SQL parser](http://www.sqlparser.com/) library .

That among others things allow to :

> Offline SQL syntax check Validates syntax without connecting to a
>   database